# How to detect integer overflow

Tags: arduino, integer-overflow

i am working on a project that has LCD and keypad. User will enter an integer value (for example students number) from keypad. Numbers will be printed to LCD side by side with keypad's keypress. Only decimal numbers will be printed, not A, B, C, D, # and *. Program will not continue until # key is pressed. After user finished entering value and pressed # key program will continue.

Here is some of my code:

```
  #include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
  #include <Keypad.h>

  const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
  const byte COLS = 4; //four columns
  char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
    {'1', '4', '7', '*'},
    {'2', '5', '8', '0'},
    {'3', '6', '9', '#'},
    {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}
  };

  byte rowPins[ROWS] = {41, 43, 45, 47};
  byte colPins[COLS] = {40, 42, 44, 46};
  Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);

  LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F, 20, 4);

  void setup() {
     lcd.begin();
  }

  void loop(){

  boolean pressedENTER = false;
  int studentsNUMBER=0;
  int keyENTERED;
  byte limit=0;
  do {
    int key = keypad.getKey();
    if (key != NO_KEY) {
      switch (key) {
        case '#': // this key will be used as ENTER key
          {
            pressedENTER = true;
            break;
          }
        case '*':
          break;
        case 'A':
          break;
        case 'B':
          break;
        case 'C': // C will clear LCD and set studentsNUMBER to 0
            studentsNUMBER=0;
            limit=0;
            lcd.clear();
          break;
        case 'D':
          break;
        default:
          keyENTERED = key - 48;
          limit++;
          if (studentsNUMBER > 3276){
            if (keyENTERED > 7){
              limit++;
            }
          }

          if (limit<=5){

              lcd.print(keyPRESSED);
              studentsNUMBER = (studentsNUMBER * 10) + keyPRESSED;
              if (studentsNUMBER < 0 or studentsNUMBER > 32767){
                studentsNUMBER=0;
                limit=0;
                lcd.clear()
                lcd.print(F("Value exceeded limits"));
                delay(1000);
            }  
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  while (pressedENTER == false);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print(F("You entered:"));
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(studentsNUMBER);
  delay(2000);
  // program continues to do something..
  }
```

Everything is working well except integer overflow problem. Let me clarify: if input is between 0 and 32767 its Ok. My code controls if value is between 0 and 32767.

But in this scenario:

User pressed 3 (studentsNUMBER is now equals to 3)

User pressed 3 (studentsNUMBER is now equals to 33)

User pressed 3 (studentsNUMBER is now equals to 333)

User pressed 3 (studentsNUMBER is now equals to 3333)

(here is the problem begins)

User pressed 3 (studentsNUMBER is now equals to 33333 **(Integer limit exceeded but i couldn't avoid it)**)

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is exact error text? also plz put printing code

Comment: The error is user can input a value over integer limits (like 99999 or 88888 or 76584). I want to check if studentsNUMBER is in limits of integer. User should not input a value which exceeds integer limits. I made some improvements in my code but it still sucks in some values. Please check my edited post again.

Comment: With my new code i check if user input 5 digits. After 5 digits i disable input. This is OK if user inputs not more than 32767. But if user inputs a value that is also 5 digits but over integer limit like 33333. I cannot control this.

Comment: Why are you using a signed data type when there is no minus key on your keypad? You never need to test for < 0 and your actual upper-bound would be 65535 instead of 32767. You still need to detect overflow, but the range of values you can handle is much larger than you think.

Comment: If you use an unsigned integer and the value after the user presses the next button is <= the value before, then you overflowed.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman You are right. But how? I tried to code but couldn't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

#### Logical Flaw In Your Code

You need to have a clear understanding on how overflow/underflow works,

```
  if (studentsNUMBER < 0 or studentsNUMBER > 32767){
    ...
  }
```

You have declared `studentsNUMBER` as an `integer` whose max value can be **32767**. Now you are comparing `studentNUMBER > 32767` which is will never be the case as `studentNUMBER` will never be able to cross the limit.

#### Suggestions

Mind that once there has been overflow/underflow, [Undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) Behavior is occurred and your program can do anything abnormal.

One of many approaches to overcome such situation can be like,

```
long result, 
int studentNUMBER, keyENTERED;
...
result = (studentsNUMBER * 10) + keyENTERED;
if (result > 32767)
{
    // overflow occurred 
}
```

Hope you will get a concept.